# Application of Differential Equation.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The rate of increase in the number of a species of fish in a lake is described by the differential equation

$$\frac{dp}{dt}=(a-b)p$$ where $p$ is the number of fish at time $t$ week, $a$, the rate of reproduction, and $b$, the mortaliry rate, with $a$ and $b$ as constants.

i)Assuming that $p=p_0$ at time $t=0$ and $a>b$, solve the differential equation and sketch its solution curve.

ii)At a certain instant, there is an outbreak of an epidemic of a disease.  The epidemic results in no more offspring of the fish being produced and the fish die at a rate directly proportional to $\sqrt{\frac{1}{p}}$.  There are 900 fish before the outbreak of the epidemic and only 400 fish are alive after 6 weeks.  Determine the length of time from the outbreak of the epidemic until all the fish of that species die.

I solved i. But I've no idea for ii. Anyone can solve for me? thanks.

Comment: set $a=0$, $b=k\sqrt{\frac{1}{p}}$ in your equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the epidemic 
$$\frac{dp}{dt}=-c\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{p}}\right)p=-c\sqrt{p}$$
Equivalently
$$\frac{dp}{p^{1/2}}=-cdt$$
Integrating in the interval $[t_1,t]$ we obtain
$$2\sqrt{p(t)}=2\sqrt{p(t_1)}-c(t-t_1)$$ 
which means that the population extincts ($p(T)=0$) at
$$T=t_1+\frac{2}{c}\sqrt{p(t_{1})}$$ 
You can also calculate the rate $c$ since you have $p(t_1)=900$ and within six weeks $t-t_1=6$ the population is $p(t)=400$ i.e.
$$2\sqrt{400}=2\sqrt{900}-6c$$ that results in $c=10/3$. So the population will be extinct within 18 weeks since
$$T-t_1=\frac{6}{10}\sqrt{900}=18$$